# component not initialised on router navigating.it initialising only when browser refreshes?

Tags: angular

when i give router navigation data doesn't updated in the router page.But when i refresh the browser updated data can be shown in the router page .i want to reload only the component.i tried router navigation by first navigated to dummy component and then navigated to the router page.is there any other better way???

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    import { NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

    import { Appsettings } from '../../../app.settings'

    import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';

    import { Router, Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

    import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

    import { BaThemeSpinner } from '../../../theme/services';

    import { ToastrService,ToastrConfig } from 'toastr-ng2';

    @Component({

      selector: 'add-service-modal',

      styleUrls: [('./cat-modal.component.scss')],

      templateUrl: './cat-modal.component.html'

    })

    export class CatModal implements OnInit {

        modalHeader: string;

        modalContent: string;

        constructor(private activeModal: NgbActiveModal,private http:Http,

    private toastrService: ToastrService, private toastrConfig: ToastrConfig,

     private router: Router, private spinner: BaThemeSpinner)

     {

            toastrConfig.timeOut = 0;

        }

        approveCategory(userId,catId)

    {

            console.log(userId);

            console.log(catId);

            this.closeModal();

            this.spinner.showBlur();

            let params  =   {

                user_id     :   userId,

                cat_id      :   catId

            }

            let result=
          this.http.post(Appsettings.API__URL+'/adminUser/approveCategory',params 

    ).map((res: Response) => res.json());

            console.log(result);

            let subresult   =   result.subscribe((data) =>{

                this.spinner.hide();

                console.log('sub result');console.log(data);console.log('sub 

    result');

                if(data.status==1)

    {

                    this.toastrService.success('Category approved!',

     'Success!');

                    this.router.navigateByUrl('/DummyComponent', 

    {skipLocationChange: true}).then(()=>

                    this.router.navigate(["/pages/manageApproval"]));


                }

                else

                {
                    this.toastrService.success(data.message, 'Failed!');
                }

                });


                }

                denyCategory(userId,catId)

               {
            console.log(userId);

            console.log(catId);

            let params  =   {

                user_id     :   userId,

                cat_id      :   catId

            }

            this.closeModal();

            this.spinner.showBlur();

            let result=

     this.http.post(Appsettings.API__URL+'/adminUser/denyCategory', params 

    ).map((res: Response) => res.json());

            console.log(result);

            let subresult   =   result.subscribe((data) =>{

             {

             skipLocationChange: true}).then(()=>

                this.router.navigate(["/pages/manageApproval"]));

                this.spinner.hide();

            });

        }

        ngOnInit() {}

        closeModal() {

        this.activeModal.close();

        }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that the code you posted is complete but from what I can gather from your question you are talking about `route params`. Depending on how you are getting your data, maybe there is a query string or something, you can use that as a route param. Then when you refresh the page the route param can be used in an activated subscription. Activated route documentation is found [here](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute).

Also [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#hero-feature-route-configuration) is a link on doing the route parameters.  Hope that helps.